# Angular equivalent of JQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, web

I want to invoke a method on click of Any div with a given class. In JQuery it was a trivial one liner. Do we have something similar in Angular?

I know we can use a (click) binding to invoke a method on click. But that would require a separate binding for each instance of the div. I want a generic way to bind every div for the given class - as we used to do with JQuery selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular you can create a custom directive, assign it to the required blocks and create a click listener via @HostListener.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div appMyDirective>
  div 1
</div>
<div appMyDirective>
  div 2
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyDirective]'
})
export class MyDirectiveDirective {

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    console.log('Привет')
  }

}
```

May be it suit you

Comment: as pointer the selector of a directive can be also a class `selector:'.myclass'`, see the docs:https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector

Answer (score 0):

Angular has absolutely different approach. Instead of querying the DOM, we typically bind the event handlers in the markup.

```html
<button (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
```

[Event binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding)

Comment: Question was about Any the div with a given class

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve,will specify the basic of using click and ngClass in angular see if it helps

In you HTML file

```
<div class="my_class" (click)="clickDiv()"  
    [ngClass]="isActive ? 'active' : 'notActive'">                
     Some content
</div>
```

In .ts file

```
isActive : boolean = false ;
clickDiv(){
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;       
}
```

Comment: Question was about Any the divs with a given class

Comment: So did the directive worked for you ? @Vikas ,as it seems it is doing pretty much the same thing of invoking a click method ,unless you have some reusable code in it

Comment: Directive worked because I want it to work for all the divs in the entire page to respond similarly to a click . Your code would require me to add the same code to each and every instancce of the div of that class. That would increase the code  size. I had asked the question specifically for the "Any div". Just the (click) is available in any Angular tutorial. Does not need a question on StackOverflow. :)